# Struggling with multiprocessing Queue

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

My structure (massively simplified) is depicted below:

```
import multiprocessing

def creator():
    # creates files
    return


def relocator():
    # moves created files
    return


create = multiprocessing.Process(target=creator)
relocate = multiprocessing.Process(target=relocator)
create.start()
relocate.start()
```

What I am trying to do is have a bunch of files created by `creator` and **as soon as** they get created have them moved to another directory by `relocator`.

The reason I want to use `multiprocessing` here is:

- I do not want `creator` to wait for the moving to be finished first because moving takes time I dont want to waste.
- Creating all the files first before starting to copy is not an option either because there is not enough space in the drive for all of them.

I want both the `creator` and `relocator` processes to be serial (one file at a time each) but run in parallel. A "log" of the actions should lool like this:

```
# creating file 1
# creating file 2 and relocating file 1
# creating file 3 and relocating file 2
# ...
# relocating last file
```

Based on what I have read, `Queue` is the way to go here.

**Strategy:** (maybe not the best one?!)

After an file gets created it will be entering the queue and after it has finished being relocated, it will be removed from the queue.

I am however having issues coding it; multiple files being created at the same time (multiple instances of `creator` running in parallel) and others...

*I would be very grateful for any ideas, hints, explanations, etc*

Comment: i cant see the issue here, your problem maybe is that that creating the files will be quicker thatn moving them, so by the time the creator is finished you still have to wait for the relocator to end. You can solve it by making the creator do the same job as the relocator when finished. Dont forget to push as many stop flags as processes you have

Comment: @Netwave Do you mind describing the last part (*"Dont forget to push as many stop flags as processes you have"*) in a bit more detail?

Comment: Ill create an answer on how I think it should be done :)

Comment: That would be great. It does not have to be too fancy (turning the creator into relocator). Let me get my head around the simple stuff first xD

Comment: Can you create the files directly in the final directory that you want them to end up in, or at least merge the 2 functions into one that creates and relocates?

Comment: @Chris_Rands No because of company policy and no because it would defeat the purpose of them running in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets take your idea and split in this features:

1. **Creator** should create files (100 for example)
2. **Relocator** should move 1 file at a time till there are no more files to move
3. Creator may end before **Relocator** so it can also
       transform himself into a **Relocator** Both have to know when to
       finish

So, we have 2 main functionalities:

```
def create(i):
    # creates files and return outpath
    return os.path.join("some/path/based/on/stuff", "{}.ext".format(i))


def relocate(from, to):
    # moves created files
    shuttil.move(from, to)
```

Now lets create our processes:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

comm_queue = Queue()

#process that create the files and push the data into the queue
def creator(comm_q):
    for i in range(100):
        comm_q.put(create(i))
    comm_q.put("STOP_FLAG") # we tell the workers when to stop, we just push one since we only have one more worker

#the relocator works till it gets an stop flag
def relocator(comm_q):
    data = comm_q.get()
    while data != "STOP_FLAG":
        if data:
            relocate(data, to_path_you_may_want)
        data = comm_q.get()

creator_process= multiprocessing.Process(target=creator, args=(comm_queue))
relocators = multiprocessing.Process(target=relocator, args=(comm_queue))
creator_process.start()
relocators .start()
```

This way we would have now a creator and a relocator, but, lets say now we want the **Creator** to start relocating when the creation job is done by it, we can just use relocator, but we would need to push one more `"STOP_FLAG"` since we would have 2 processes relocating

```
def creator(comm_q):
    for i in range(100):
        comm_q.put(create(i))
    for _ in range(2):
        comm_q.put("STOP_FLAG")
    relocator(comm_q)
```

Lets say we want now an arbitrary number of relocator processes, we should adapt our code a bit to handle this, we would need the `creator` method to be aware of how many flags to notify the other processes when to stop, our resulting code would look like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, cpu_count

comm_queue = Queue()

#process that create the files and push the data into the queue
def creator(comm_q, number_of_subprocesses):
    for i in range(100):
        comm_q.put(create(i))
    for _ in range(number_of_subprocesses + 1): # we need to count ourselves
        comm_q.put("STOP_FLAG")
    relocator(comm_q)

#the relocator works till it gets an stop flag
def relocator(comm_q):
    data = comm_q.get()
    while data != "STOP_FLAG":
        if data:
            relocate(data, to_path_you_may_want)
        data = comm_q.get()

num_of_cpus = cpu_count() #we will spam as many processes as cpu core we have
creator_process= Process(target=creator, args=(comm_queue, num_of_cpus))
relocators = [Process(target=relocator, args=(comm_queue)) for _ in num_of_cpus]
creator_process.start()
for rp in relocators:
    rp.start()
```

Then you will have to **WAIT** for them to finish:

```
creator_process.join()
for rp in relocators:
    rp.join()
```

You may want to check at the [`multiprocessing.Queue` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue)

Specially to the [`get` method](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.get) (is a blocking call by default)

> Remove and return an item from the queue. If optional args block is
>   True (the default) and timeout is None (the default), block if
>   necessary until an item is available.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am going through it and probably will get back to you with questions.

Comment: NItpicking: since you are importing like `from X import Y` you cannot call them as `X.Y`.

Comment: Is there a reason for the `create` and `creator` to be two different functions? Same for `relocate` and `relocator`.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis, no there is no reason for that, just to abstract the functionality, so it doesnt mess the code and the answer to be clearer :)